# Jquery: Get the texts from a txt file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm new to Jquery. I made a simple text/quote slider that calls the texts from the same html file, but I need it to get the texts from an external ".txt" file instead. I'm intended to use this slider in many other pages, and I don't want to edit each page when I want to edit/remove these texts.

I've read that `$('#div-name').load("../textfile.txt")` method would do the the trick, but I can't make it work with my slider although I tested it in a server. Do you maybe know how to do it? Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="updates">
    <a href="redirect-link1.html">Text 1</a>
    <a href="redirect-link2.html">Text 2</a>
    <a href="redirect-link3.html">Text 3</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#updates {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
}
#updates a {
    width: 100%;
    color: rgb(0,0,0);
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
var slider = $("#updates"),
    items = slider.children('a'),
    length = items.length,
    i = 0,

    change = function () {
        items.eq(i).fadeOut(300, function () {
            i += 1;
            if (i === length) {
                i = 0;
            }
            items.eq(i).fadeIn(300);
        });
    };
    items.not(':first').hide();
    setInterval(change, 5000);
});
```

Comment: The problem is once you call `load()`, your the elements referred by the  `items` variable is removed from the dom... what you can do is reinitialize the `items` and `i` variable in the success callback of the `load` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.get` method is what you looking for.

**EDIT 1: change method edit + removed .txt empty lines**

**EDIT 2: dump links testing**

**EDIT 3: using links from an external file**

```js
jQuery(function () {
  const
    // Items container
    slider = jQuery("#updates"),
    // Text file containing links
    url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/decryptingfuture/placeholders/main/links.txt"

  // Initial iteration
  let i = 0

  // Get text contents
  jQuery.get(url, function (data) {
    // Split lines and iterate them
    data.split('\n').map((block) => {
      // Skip empty lines
      if (block !== '') {
        // Append each line to the container
        slider.append(block)
      }
    })

    // Children to be slided
    const items = slider.children()

    change = function () {
      items.eq(i).fadeOut(100, function () {
        ++i;

        if (i >= items.length) i = 0

        items.eq(i).fadeIn(100)
      })
    }

    items.not(':first').hide()

    setInterval(change, 500)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="updates"></div>
```

Comment: Kind of works, but interestingly this code runs the slider only once, and then stops. I'm not sure what to improve in the change method, since I'm quite new to jquery. Do you maybe know?

Comment: @tez I have updated the code, should work well now

Comment: Now `idx` causes problem... When there are pure texts in the txt file like yours, it works fine. However in my txt, each of the lines are written as `<a href="redirect-link1.html">Text 1</a>` since each of the lines must refer a different link when clicked. When I use your function with my txt file, slider first shows ID no, and then the text. And when I remove `${idx}:` from the function, then it shows one empty slide, and then the text. Please include `a href` links in your example txt and you'll see what I mean. How can we solve this?

Comment: @tez could you share an example of your `.txt` file? I have tried to use a dump links instead of pure text and it worked fine. You may also provide a better control over an empty lines like `if (block.replace(/\s+/g, '') !== '') {...}` instead of just doing `if (block !== '') {...}` if needed.

Comment: My `.txt` is very simple. It only has these links in each line: `<a href="redirect-link1.html">Text 1</a>`. There's no additional space, or anything else. And CSS of these `a` tags are still the same with my first message

Comment: Hi is the 2nd edit in your code final? I'm afraid it's not answering the topic in this state, since it doesn't call the links from a `txt` file anymore. Actually your previous code was really great except the lining issue with `a href` links. Do you think it could be solved?

Comment: @tez I created an external file containing links. When you run this snippet, does it work as it should or not?

Comment: Works like a charm! Although now the lines without `a` tag in the `txt` file seem to make problem, it won't bother. The code fulfills its purpose perfectly. I'm so much thankful for all your effort!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to help.